# How to set USER_SUBVOL_RM_ALLOWED capability?

Tags: btrfs

I try to remove btrfs snapshot as a normal user. [I've read](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88932/why-cant-a-regular-user-delete-a-btrfs-subvolume), that a user needs to have some special capability/right set: `USER_SUBVOL_RM_ALLOWED`. How to grant such capability to user??

Comment: The second answer to that question says there's a mount option to enable that. Did you try it?

Comment: Yes. with `sudo mount -t btrfs -o USER_SUBVOL_RM_ALLOWED,compress,rw,noacl,noatime,autodefrag  /dev/mapper/adam-docs /home/Adama-docs/Adam` with no effect.

Comment: does that mount without errors?

Comment: @muru, oh, you are right. It failed with `bad option` error message.

Comment: I think mount options are case sensitive, and the answer mentioned a lower case option.

Comment: Suggest an edit to that answer to make things clearer, if you can.

Comment: @muru Answer edited.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I meant the second answer to the linked question. Your own was clear

Answer (score 2):

This capability concerns mount point, not user (as it is suggested by the referenced question).

To add such capability one must remount/mount the filesystem with `-o user_subvol_rm_allowed` option (case sensitive).

e.g. this is the mount command I use to mount the btrfs partition with my documents:

`sudo mount -t btrfs -o remount,user_subvol_rm_allowed,compress,rw,noacl,noatime,autodefrag /dev/mapper/mydocs /home/adam/docs`